# My query has no errors, but is running forever and I can't figure out why

Tags: sql, loops, amazon-redshift

Is there any error in here that would sugggest a loop? whenever i run this query, it goes on forever then errors out due to time. I'm attempting to left join but needed to create a new column because there wasn't any matching keywords.

```
select 
table1.column1
table2.column2 
from table1
left join table2
on table1.ID = SUBSTRING(table2.details, CHARINDEX('[string]', table2.details) + LEN('[string]'), 12)
where column1 like '[string]'
```

the output i'm looking for has all the values on table1. and then IF there is matching keyword data in table 2, it outputs it, if not, its blank or null i guess.

Potential example output.

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| string | substring |
| string | null |
| string | null |
| string | substring |
| string | substring |

```
select 
table1.column1
table2.column2 
from table1
left join table2
on table1.ID = SUBSTRING(table2.details, CHARINDEX('[string]', table2.details) + LEN('[string]'), 12)
where column1 like '[string]'
```

the output i'm looking for has all the values on table1. and then IF there is matching keyword data in table 2, it outputs it, if not, its blank or null i guess.

Potential example output.

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| string | substring |
| string | null |
| string | null |
| string | substring |
| string | substring |

Comment: Side note, your query won't run because you don't have commas in your select statement.

Comment: how many rows has table1 and table 2